# как сделать так, чтобы видео воспроизводилось автоматически СО ЗВУКОМ (без muted) в html

Tags: javascript, html, css, видео

```
    <html>
     <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>autoplay</title>
     </head> 
     <body>
      <video width="400" height="320" controls="controls" autoplay>
       <source src="video/snowman.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'>
       <source src="video/snowman.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
       <source src="video/snowman.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"'>
       Тег video не поддерживается вашим браузером.
      </video>
     </body> 
    </html>
```

Comment: Никак! muted запомнил только ваш браузер, так как при последнем просмотре другого видео вы решили выключить звук. Принудительно завысить громкость воспроизведения в обход текущего состояния браузера не получится

Comment: @DiD нет, просто современные браузеры не допускают возможность автозапуска видео со звуком. С другой стороны, сплошь и рядом звук включается по ховеру над блоком проигрывателя.

Comment: А ну тогда получается можно включить по Trusted event

Answer (score 0):

#### Краткий ответ

В HTML - никак.

#### Не краткий ответ

По стандарту, во всех браузерах при `autoplay`, видео воспроизводится без звука. Это было сделано для того, чтобы веб-сайты не показывали рекламу на громкости 100%, на полную катушку.

Что можно попытаться сделать так это включить громкость с помощью JavaScript, вот так:

```js
const videoNode = document.querySelector('video')
videoNode.muted = false
```